# How to dump all my Constraints

Tags: symfony

is there a way to display every entities and fields that have a constraint ?

So I can check if there is no misconfiguration between validator.yml and Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints in entity file.

Comment: Thats bad idea. You should do by `test` using phpunit. If you want, to check field I suggest debug by phpStorm or repl like `Psysh` http://psysh.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$metadata = $validator->getMetadataFor('_class_name_');

foreach($metadata->getConstrainedProperties() as $property) {
    echo $property."\n";
    foreach ($metadata->getPropertyMetadata($property) as $metadatap) {
        \dump($metadatap->getConstraints());
    }
    echo "-----------\n";
}
```